# MySQLSyntaxErrorException using JPQL "WHERE TYPE(x) = X"

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I've got this abstract Vet class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "vet")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "vet_type")
    public abstract class Vet implements Serializable {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "vet_id")
      @TableGenerator(name = "idGenTable", table = "id_gen", pkColumnName = "gen_name", valueColumnName = "gen_value", pkColumnValue = "vet_id_gen", initialValue = 1)
      @GeneratedValue(generator = "idGenTable")
      private Integer id;

      ...
    }
```

Then these 2 extension classes, `InHouseVet` and `ExternalVet`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "in_house_vet")
@DiscriminatorValue("in_vet")
public class InHouseVet extends Vet {
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "external_vet")
@DiscriminatorValue("ext_vet")
public class ExternalVet extends Vet {
   ...
}
```

And the query for getting just the `InHouseVet`:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vet v WHERE TYPE(v) = InHouseVet");
List<Vet> vets = query.getResultList();
```

This results in

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   Unknown column 'ext_vet' in 'where clause'

Can someone see what has gone wrong here?

Comment: Would you be so kind to elaborate the purpose of this code and what your expectations would be? Thank you ;)

Comment: Hi Casper, I'm trying out a query using WHERE TYPE-clause (instead of selecting directly FROM InHouseVet). What I expect is a list of Vets of type InHouseVet.

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL query being executed?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet above, Hibernate (version 4.3.7 Final) generates the following.. (notice the missing quotes within the 1st and 2nd when-clause).

```
select
    vet0_.vet_id as vet_id2_10_,
    vet0_.name as name3_10_,
    vet0_.qualification as qualific4_10_,
    vet0_1_.salary as salary1_8_,
    vet0_2_.country as country1_6_,
    vet0_2_.visiting_fees as visiting2_6_,
    vet0_.vet_type as vet_type1_10_ 
from
    vet vet0_ 
left outer join
    in_house_vet vet0_1_ 
        on vet0_.vet_id=vet0_1_.vet_id 
left outer join
    external_vet vet0_2_ 
        on vet0_.vet_id=vet0_2_.vet_id 
where
    case 
        when vet0_1_.vet_id is not null then in_vet 
        when vet0_2_.vet_id is not null then ext_vet 
        when vet0_.vet_id is not null then 'Vet' 
    end='in_vet'
```

This has been reported as a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8974).